# How to set color data (min and max) in colormap manually?

Tags: matlab

[image]How to set color data (min and max) in colormap manually? I want to do it without using toolbox(Colormap Editor).

Comment: do you mean `caxis`?

Comment: I add image, which explains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean to use the `CLim` property on the current axis?  Try:

```
set(gca, 'CLim', [cmin cmax]);
```

Alternatively, you can do what zeeMonkeez suggests and use [`caxis`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/caxis.html), which does `set` in this fashion under the hood:

```
caxis([cmin cmax]);
```